# Dynamic Collection Mapping: Add missing records in collection

Tags: laravel, eloquent, collection-select

I have the following

```
->select(DB::raw('source as Source, customer as Customers, COUNT(*) as count'))
->groupBy('source', 'customer')
->get();
```

I get the follwing results

```
Illuminate\Support\Collection {#460 ▼
  #items: array:4 [▼
    0 => {#466 ▼
      +"Source": "Facebook"
      +"Customer": "Yes"
      +"count": 227
    }
    1 => {#463 ▼
      +"Source": "PinInterest"
      +"Customer": "Yes"
      +"count": 370
    }
    2 => {#465 ▼
      +"Source": "PinInterest"
      +"Customer": "No"
      +"count": 133
    }
    3 => {#467 ▼
      +"Source": "Whatsapp"
      +"Customer": "No"
      +"count": 254
    }
  ]
}
```

Now Source can be 1 - 10 different channels depending on the customer.
Now Customer Be Yes or No.

How do I add modify collection to add Source Facebook, Customer No and Count 0, and Source WhatsApp, Customer Yes and Count 0

Source : Facebook
Customer : Yes
Count : 227

Source : Facebook
Customer : No
Count : 0

Source : Whatsapp
Customer : No
count : 254

Source : Whatsapp
Customer : Yes
count : 0

Comment: what does this mean `Finally I want the collection to be like [ Facebook "No" doesn't Exits and Whatsapp "Yes" doesn't Exists]`

Comment: Sorry, I corrected.  Table does not have any row for Facebook. Also Table has a row for WhatsApp Customer but the name is not there so count is 0.

Comment: will there be only 2 options as customer Yes and No? or there can be many

Comment: @MKhalidJunaid, Only Yes and No.

Comment: if you just want to do it for properties whose values you know, then how about just using [transform()](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/collections#method-transform) from collection,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using laravel's collection helpers you can add missing data in your original collection as

### Transformation

```
/** Result from original query */
$collection = collect([
    ["Source"=>"Facebook","Customer"=> "Yes","count"=> 227],
    ["Source"=>"PinInterest","Customer"=> "Yes","count"=> 370],
    ["Source"=>"PinInterest","Customer"=>"No","count"=> 133],
    ["Source"=>"Whatsapp","Customer"=> "No","count"=>254]
  ]);

/** Unique list of sources */
$sources = $collection->pluck('Source')->unique();

/** Unique list of customers */
$customers = collect(["Yes","No","May Be"]);

$sources->each(function ($source, $sourceKey) use (&$collection,$customers) {
    if($collection->where('Source', $source)->count() < count($customers)){
        $customers->each(function ($customer, $customerKey) use (&$collection,$source) {
            if($collection->where('Source', $source)->where('Customer', $customer)->count() === 0){
                $collection = $collection->merge([["Source"=>$source,"Customer"=> $customer,"count"=>0]]);                
            }
        });
    }
});

/** Sort and print */
echo "<pre>";
print_r($collection->sortBy('Source')->toArray());
echo "</pre>";
```

### Output

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [Source] => Facebook
            [Customer] => Yes
            [count] => 227
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [Source] => Facebook
            [Customer] => No
            [count] => 0
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [Source] => Facebook
            [Customer] => May Be
            [count] => 0
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [Source] => PinInterest
            [Customer] => Yes
            [count] => 370
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [Source] => PinInterest
            [Customer] => No
            [count] => 133
        )

    [6] => Array
        (
            [Source] => PinInterest
            [Customer] => May Be
            [count] => 0
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [Source] => Whatsapp
            [Customer] => No
            [count] => 254
        )

    [7] => Array
        (
            [Source] => Whatsapp
            [Customer] => Yes
            [count] => 0
        )

    [8] => Array
        (
            [Source] => Whatsapp
            [Customer] => May Be
            [count] => 0
        )

)
```